# css position sticky doesn't work with bootstrap 4 class row

Tags: css

I'm having trouble pinning a menu on a website.
When the page content has a DIV with Bootstrap 4 ROW class, this DIV overrides the menu.
This is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<main class="main-container">
  <h4>
  Scroll page down to see the HEADER fixed on top
  </h4>
  <header class="main-header">HEADER</header>
  <div class="main-content">
    <h4>MAIN CONTENT TITLE</h4>
    <div class="row"><!-- if delete this DIV, works fine -->
      <div class="col">
        left col
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        right col
      </div>
    </div><!-- row -->
  </div><!-- main-content -->
  <footer class="main-footer">FOOTER</footer>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

And here the CSS code:

```
.main-container{ max-width:600px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 10px green; padding:10px; margin-top:40px;}
.main-container *{padding:10px;background:#aaa; border:dashed 5px #000;}
.main-container * + *{margin-top:20px;}
.main-header{ height:50px; background:#aaa; border-color:red;}
.main-content{ min-height:1000px;}
.main-header{position:-webkit-sticky; position:sticky; top:0;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/WRobynson/qhdfbjmv/10/

Please, can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get the menu to fill the full width of the viewport, or are you talking about the div that floats on top of it when scrolling?

Comment: SOLVED! With a  "**z-index: 10**" in "**.main-header**" class. Credits to **@hugocsl**. Thanks.

Comment: I was going to say, I think a Z index is the fix there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add z-index in main-header.

```css
.main-container{ max-width:600px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 10px green; padding:10px; margin-top:40px;}
.main-container *{padding:10px;background:#aaa; border:dashed 5px #000;}
.main-container * + *{margin-top:20px;}
.main-header{ height:50px; background:#aaa; border-color:red; z-index:100;}
.main-content{ min-height:1000px;}
.main-header{position:-webkit-sticky; position:sticky; top:0;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<main class="main-container">
  <header class="main-header">HEADER</header>
  <div class="main-content">
    <h4>MAIN CONTENT TITLE</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        left col
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        right col
      </div>
    </div><!-- row -->
  </div><!-- main-content -->
  <footer class="main-footer">FOOTER</footer>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```